# Call scala script function

Tags: scala

I have:

**sum.scala**

```
def sum(a : Int, b : Int) = println(a+b)
```

and I want to call that function from the CLI
by doing something like:

```
scala sum.scala.sum(3, 4)
```

Is that even possible?, and if so what is the syntax of the command that I need to type in the CLI to make it work?

I want to do it without creating an object to wrap the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `scala -help` to see the CLI options.

The options you need here are:

```
-i <file>    preload <file> before starting the repl
-e <string>  execute <string> as if entered in the repl
```

Example:

```
> scala -i sum.scala -e "sum(3, 4)"
7
```

Comment: Not as "smooth" as I would have liked it to be but it works. Thanks!